# creating help file along with my ios project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I am currently working on a project that I would like to create a help file for but I was hoping someone could suggest the best practices for this.

The help file would mainly be for me, and say anyone in the future that might take over my project etc, and would mostly identify objects or pieces of code that I have implemented and a description of what they are for etc.

This is something I have found in the apple developer library, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OnlineHelp/OnlineHelp.html) but im not sure what this is or how to use it..

Comment: I document projects in an internal wiki.

Comment: is adding a .txt file to the project not interactive/synchronized enough? of course, you could also always add comments to the code as you go, but i'm assuming you're looking for something more consolidated.

Comment: Yes I think its more consolidation and detail of the help/comments that sometimes lacks in commenting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to go with Apples [HeaderDocs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001215-CH345-SW1) as it it already built in it generates very similar results to those that are created with the application listed above (re: html output)

Its simple as you just use structured comments inside your header tags along the lines of

```
/*!
 @class myclass
 @discussion enter any text here that can span multiple lines etc
*/
```

The great thing being you can comment methods, functions, classes, parameters etc.

then when you compile the headers inside cmd line using the gathered headers script it will combine all of your header comments into a MasterDoc.html inside a directory you specify like so

```
>headerdoc2html -o outputdir ExampleHeaders
>gatherheaderdoc outputdir
```

This style of documenting suites me personally because I like to comment my code alot however I lack the structure that this will now bring to my comments, so really its killing two birds with one stone.

The only let down I feel is that it might not be as flexible as those listed before this post... So yea I guess users prefrence... Now off to learn more

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at **[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html)** ? It supports multiple languages and as it picks comments directly from source code your help documentation and source code are more likely to be always in sync.

Doxygen supports **C++** , **C** and **Objective-C** out of the box.

I have personally found that if you start with good doxygen documentation, fellow developers are more likely to pick it up and keep it up to date.

Comment: cool I'm going to check this out tonight, I will wait a few more hours before accepting any asnwers to see if anyone else has anything they can offer hanks again.

Comment: Im trying to install it now and I cannot see objective c support.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) which is available on GitHub.

It uses Doxygen markup, but outputs html, docsets, etc in a format that looks just like Apple's documentation.

Docsets will be useful to you because you can install them into Xcode and have help directly while working on the code.